# Laravel 5.1 trying to get property of non object eloquent relationship, handle error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

OrganizationsController.php

```
public function user_index()
{   
    if(!is_null(Organization::find(Auth::user()->player->organization))) 
    $organization = Organization::find(Auth::user()->player->organization->id);
    else $organization=null;

    return view('organizations.user_index', [ 'organization' => $organization ]);
}
```

To avoid "Trying to get property of non-object" when "player" have no "organization" I used this code. But it  doesnt seem very nice. There is a better way to obtain this? Maybe im wrong but with this method there is a useless query, am I right?

Table Player: id, name

Table Organization: id, name, player_id

Comment: Can you give me the the columns of your database?

Comment: yes,thx. but I think they are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `user` hasOne `player`, and `player` hasOne `organization`, and these relationships are setup correctly, there is no need for either `Organization::find()` at all. The `organization` attribute is going to be the loaded `Organization` object already, so there is no need to re-find it.

```
public function user_index() {
    // default to null
    $organization = null;

    // make sure there is an authenticated user and it has a player
    if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->player) {
        // if the player has an organization, this will be the Organzation object
        // if the player does not have an organization, this will be null
        $organization = Auth::user()->player->organization;
    }

    return view('organizations.user_index', [ 'organization' => $organization ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for this check you might get one unnecessary SQL query executed. You can get rid of this if you do:

```
if(Organization::find(Auth::user()->player->organization_id)
```

instead of

```
if(!is_null(Organization::find(Auth::user()->player->organization)))
```

This way you check **organization_id** that is stored in **player** before trying to fetch **organization** from the database.

Comment: actually i dont have an "organization_id" ... foreign key is on organization

Comment: Could you paste your relation definition? If player can have only one organization then I expected the foreign key to be stored in player

Comment: well,player can have only one organization and an organization can have only one player. I put foreign key on organization :)

Comment: In this case there is no way of checking if an organization with given player_id exists in the database without executing a query on organizations table